# How can I Validate forms with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Thanks to some awesome people on stack overflow i was able to get my classes toggled and got my form slide up and down correctly. I'm having issues validating the form before it becomes submitted. Could someone help me with a step in the right direction? I just want the validation to check that the fields have some text in them before allowing the submit.
        
        
        
        
        Assignment 6

```
    <!-- video  https://youtu.be/XEoWYcolaEM -->

    <style>
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
    }
    a {
        color: blue;
    }
    #welcome p strong {
        color: navy;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    #welcome p:first-of-type {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    section {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    /* main container */
    #main {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #e0e0ff;
        position: relative;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* form container */
    #loginDiv {
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 650px;
        top: 6px;
        z-index: 100;
        border: 1px solid navy;
    }
    /* paragraph that shows the text "Login" which is clicked on to display/remove the form */
    #login {
        margin: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        padding: 5px 0 2px 30px;
    }
    #login:hover {
        background-color: rgb(110,138,195);
    }
    /*  plus sign icon for login form */
    .plus {
        background: url(img_open.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
        background-color: rgb(110,138,195);
    }
    /* minus sign icon for login form */
    .minus {
        background: url(img_close.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
    }
    /*form is hidden when the page loads */
    #loginDiv form {
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        display: none;
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }
    #loginDiv label {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    }
    #loginDiv input {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        border: 1px solid navy;
    }
    #loginDiv input:focus {
        background-color: rgb(110,138,195);
        border: 2px solid navy;
    }
    #loginDiv input[type=button] {
        width: 100px;
    }
    footer {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
    }
    /* ad is not shown when the page loads  */
    #ad {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: absolute;
        left: 330px;
        top: -500px;  /* you can change this inbitially for viewing purposes only but be sure to set it back */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-image: url(ad.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    /* close button on ad */
    #adbtn {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-right-width: 1px;
        background-color: #fff;
        font-size: 3em;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
          //Fading in Advertisent
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#ad").animate({
          top: '100px',

          },(5000));


          //Closing The Advertisement
          $("#adbtn").click(function(){
          $("#ad").fadeOut(5000);
          });   

    $(".plus").click(function(){
          $("form").slideToggle(1000);  // half second duration
          $(this).toggleClass("plus").toggleClass("minus");

    $('button').click(function(){
        $("form").val(1);
    });
    }); // end function





            }); // end function

          </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <!-- main container -->
    <div id="main">
      <section id="loginDiv"> 
        <!-- when this is clicked on the below form should be displayed and plus sign should change to minus sign-->
        <p id="login" class="plus">Login</p>
        <form>
          <p>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="pw">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="button" value="Submit">
          </p>

          <!-- placeholder for response if form data is correct/incorrect -->
          <p id="error"> </p>
        </form>
      </section>
      <section id="welcome">
        <h1>Welcome to the Local jQuery User Group Website</h1>
        <p> <strong>Click the login button at the top of the page to login. To become a member please <a href="#">Register</a></strong> </p>
        <h2>About this page layout:</h2>
        <p> The main container (parent) has 'relative' positioning so that the 'login' container can be absolutley positioned with respect to
          that main container. Otherwise, it would default to being absolutley positioned with respect to the window. </p>
        <p> In order for the login panel to be placed on top of the page  we need to use  absolute positioning, otherwise,
          it would move the rest of the content down as done in the FAQ assignment. Technically, absolute positioning takes that element out of
          the normal flow of the document, so that it is on top of the page. The 'ad' is also absolutely positioned to the same main container. </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>This week's agenda:</h2>
        <p>There will be a live meeting this Tuesday evening from 7:00pm to 8:00pm PST using our WebEx Conferencing Software.
          It will be recorded! Please note that the code samples will be available on our GitHub repository. </p>
      </section>
      <footer> Copyright &copy; Local jQuery User Group </footer>

      <!--  ad which is absolutely positioned -500px from the top so you do not see it when page loads-->
      <div id="ad">
        <div id="adbtn"> X </div>
      </div>

      <!-- end main container --> 
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "*Assignment 6*" What is this? School work? I sure hope you're going to properly cite Stack Overflow in your work when you hand it in to your prof.

Comment: Yeah I'm taking a javascript class and of course I will. My professor recommended this site

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into [jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation easy, whilst still offering plenty of customization options.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can learn from this. I'll just give you an example with one of your fields and a submit button. Initially the submit button is disabled, then you can use the keypress event to check if 1 or more characters are entered and enable the submit button.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/8w89v3tp/1/

HTML:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<button class="js-submit">submit</button>
```

JS:

```
var $submit = $('.js-submit');
var $username = $('#username');

$submit.attr('disabled', true);

$username.keypress(function() {
    if ( $username.val().length > 0 ) {
    $submit.attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

$submit.on('click', function(){
  // do something
});
```